# Typed function to create output based on input with refinement and controlled return types

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of different inputs:

```
interface StringInput {
  _tag: "_string";
}

interface NumberInput {
  _tag: "_number";
}

interface ListInput {
  _tag: "_list";
}

type Input = StringInput | NumberInput | ListInput;
```

Along with the corresponding outputs:

```
class StringOutput {
  _tag = "StringOutput" as const;
  constructor(_: StringInput) {}
}

class NumberOutput {
  _tag = "NumberOutput" as const;
  constructor(_: NumberInput) {}
}

class ListOutput {
  _tag = "ListOutput" as const;
  constructor(_: ListInput) {}
}

type Output = StringOutput | NumberOutput | ListOutput;
```

I'd like to have a function that creates the right `output` given an `input`. The function should be well-typed especially in its implementation.

I'm stuck with two attemps, each of which solves half of the problem.

Attempt `1`: `switch`. It is a [well-known improvement possibility](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) for TypeScript. The input parameter `i` get refined, which is something I need in order to call constructor of the corresponding output object. On the other hand the generic `I` does not get refined, causing the problem with the return type.

```
namespace Attempt1 {

  type RemoveUn<S> = S extends `_${infer R}` ? R : S

  type InputOutputMap = {
    [K in Input["_tag"]]: Extract<Output,  { _tag: `${Capitalize<RemoveUn<K>>}Output` }>
  }

  function createValueOfObjKey<
    const I extends Input
  >(i: I): InputOutputMap[I["_tag"]] {
    switch(i._tag) {
      case "_string": {
        return new StringOutput(i); // error
      }
      case "_number": {
        return new NumberOutput(i); // error
      }
      case "_list": {
        return new ListOutput(i); // error
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Attempt `2`: `indexed access types`. The compiler does quite well controlling them, so what I return must be in line with what I have stated in the signature. But I lost the refinement on `i` and I'm not able to restore it.

```
namespace Attempt2 {

  type RemoveUn<S> = S extends `_${infer R}` ? R : S

  type InputOutputMap = {
    [K in Input["_tag"]]: Extract<Output,  { _tag: `${Capitalize<RemoveUn<K>>}Output` }>
  }

  function createValueOfObjKey<
    const I extends Extract<Input, { _tag: K }>,
    const K extends Input["_tag"] = I["_tag"]
  >(i: I): InputOutputMap[K] {
    return {
      get _string() {
        return new StringOutput(i as StringInput);
      },
      get _number() {
        return new NumberOutput(i as NumberInput);
      },
      get _list() {
        return new ListOutput(i as ListInput);
      }
    }[i._tag];
  }

}
```

Any idea? [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=5.2.0-dev.20230627#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-oBwGgRcEHAFBaHILBcHPmwr5OC4zCoXBx4YQBQEgbieEETRxFUMR7juOQRIkmSFLUrS9IAEzMqa3jspyPL8kKorilKMrysgSqquqmrarqBpskaaAmsgZoWti1q2oEX7Oq6gF+Hu3p+oGwahuG2JRmQsZMPGpBJvgKYdsAGZZpJuZCgWRYlkR5bsbp1a1mA9aAQgTYthA7adt2vYDkOI6Pkc5rTgpWRBhg9l+FGMavEwLplhGmUTsgLrybOimWV69C+usu5NVgvqLsuq7ru6ihbvgzqHl+dGAV+VBYBAJDsMEWADA+NE-lNmEMaBKJVNiy71Fk60TNBx58JVNGTdNSHaPNR40aNq0YsheHbbd2h7YRh2ESdNDOBwF3jbRy30dhTGbcAD2fM9rGPnwDrAHedg+v8nFAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGBVJm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz it is an interesting approach. Do you think it's not possible to eliminate the "cast" to K in line 27? If not, proceed with the answer, thanks!

Comment: The safe "upcast"?  I don't think it's possible, no.  The compiler gets confused with the intersection.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort of relationship between `i._tag` and the input and output types isn't very easily supported by TypeScript.  I consider this strongly related to what I call "correlated union types" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Conceptually you could just put the three constructors in an object called `ctors` and then have your function return `new ctors[i._tag](i)` and it should type check.  In practice the compiler doesn't really understand it directly.

You can refactor to use generics and indexed access types as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), but it's not incredibly straightforward.  The idea is to come up with a "basic" mapping type , like your `InputOutputMap` but for the input.  I'll call it `TagInputMap` (and rename yours to `TagOutputMap`, since it's analogous):

```
type TagInputMap = { [T in Input as T["_tag"]]: T }
```

From this we can then start describing what we're doing.  Let's define `TagInput<K>` as the intended input to `createValueOfObjKey` as follows:

```
type TagInput<K extends keyof TagInputMap> = { _tag: K } & TagInputMap[K]
```

This could almost just be `TagInputMap[K]`, but then when you call `createValueOfObjKey(i)`, the compiler would fail to infer `K` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#51612](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51612)).  Hence the "redundant" [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).

Now `ctors` can be explicitly written as a mapped type from `TagInputMap` to `TagOutputMap`:

```
const ctors: {
  [P in keyof TagInputMap]:
  new (_: TagInputMap[P]) => TagOutputMap[P]
} = {
  _list: ListOutput,
  _number: NumberOutput,
  _string: StringOutput
}
```

and finally the function implementation:

```
function createValueOfObjKey<K extends keyof TagInputMap>(i: TagInput<K>) {
  const tag: K = i._tag
  return new ctors[tag](i)
}
```

Again, this could almost be `new ctors[i._tag](i)`, but the intersection confuses the compiler.  We want `i._tag` to be seen only as `K` here, but the compiler sees it as `K & InputMap[K]["_tag"]` which causes things to break (it will fall back to a union like `K & ("_string" | "_number" | "_list")` and fail).  The assignment to `tag` of type `K` is the most expedient and still type-safe way to fix it.

---

And let's try it out from the caller's side:

```
const ret = createValueOfObjKey({ _tag: "_list" })
// const ret: ListOutput
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=5.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5gSRABwFcxkBvZAfTDiwC5kAiCgZw2wYG5kBfAKFEixEKAHKEAtgCNoeIiXJUa9JiAnSonHv3DR4SZABlgrWcTKVqdRhQA2xsJr5gAnvhSmSAXjRsQuAmYAPshiUjIBJMFGJhEcvLwubsgAKjQeALJw+Mje5ADaycigyB7IcMwpeUyWDAC6tfSFTq4oqf5yADwA0sgQAB6QIAAmFQDWEM4A9jApaRGZ+AB8OeaKVj3cyABks+3EC3ldtfG8CDblFeiYfgDyxHKrlisMV9h3YHIMZRUIkyCsXF+-wwhAQYEmUAAFBR6K8-B4AJTmTZ8M4XEJqaDvB4KJ7eBihdTY4hfcrIIEA8l-VhQUHgqEwjFhKCI5FaNHMCrRMDE+QWGjPbm80k-algQFi2lgiHQ+jc1nkFEJFrIXkrOFYNXBQlY+5BQz2XknRIoABKEHEkwAbhAAKogDqoZbeVC9AYQYYVAAGFAAJKRQDBoMhTdwvcgAPwh5Cw5VJNq8hYrfI9YoeKprOoNZAAUQGUEQYA6vIANI8lMgvf6AMJZYDUOwALwgHXNlpt9u6i0W3F54e4yz48QpJGlUGY9FIvGQyDyAAUiiBkOMpjM2hksg1p8gQBAAO7IWW7Df4ee1JGeZYJvVgA5z46bXLb2z2OWGm8l5+qZn0HVQUvPjS2Cwr4mo3rwQ4wIQIBgsAfzklAEBwJAABqcA2IQEA3DANySAAVl0EzdG6gwjMuEzTMe8xZIskLAI0cydF0ixIlOM4jsglj0D03jAAAdGs26IWAhBQEuu4HmOzB5JYtR0QiEHDmKyDCSsCCIchEBoRhWE4fhhHOJCuIVkwdisF83AKQA9FZVLAipEBgG+rBGkAA)

Comment: I was able to remove the need of the explicit intersection with `K` but I don't know if I like [my version](https://cutt.ly/jwyZdCcn) more.

I had to change the definition of `TagInputMap` as well. You are giving names to the keys by using an `as` clause, but without the intersection the connection with `K` is completely lost inside `createValueOfObjKey` in this way.